# No displayed text when calling Checkbutton()

Tags: python-3.x, macos, tkinter

I am running tkinter for Python 3 on MacOS and I've run into a problem that I can't solve through google searches.  When I call Checkbutton() and add a text parameter, no text is apparent in the window.  This is true in even the most sterile of contexts:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
test = IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text = 'test', variable = test).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

The resulting window looks like this:

[image]

I am not sure if I'm just missing something blatantly obvious, but every example I have found online looks more or less like the code above and they have no problems displaying the text.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The text displays fine for me, Windows!0 and python3.8.  You need to tell us more about your environment.  Did you try using a Label rather than a Checkbutton?

Comment: Label() works as expected.  I am using Python 3.7.6 which is in turn using tkinter 8.5.  I am running it all on a laptop with macOS Catalina v. 10.15.6, though I'm not sure that that would affect anything.

Comment: Okay, so I updated to Python 3.9.0 and that seemed to fix the problem.  Thanks for the help and your time, I would not have thought to update Python if not for your question.